# How to Get Logged-in to "Remote WP Site" from my local script (in Same Browser)?

Tags: login, wp-login-form, remote, remote-login

In Wordpress, is it possible:

- To "make my current browser" to get "logged-in" to the a WP site, from a script in my localhost?

Means, i will be running a script in my `localhost`:

- `http://localhost/do_login.php`

And after that, in the same browser, when i go to:

- `https://www.my_remote_wpsite.com/wp-admin`

I should already be logged in there.
So my local script will make my current browser logged-in into the remote WP site.

How can it be done please?

Answer (score 1):

Can't be done without a lot of wotk, cookies are sent only to the host doing the login. If your webserver does the login then the browser don't have the cookies.

I guess you can write some script that imports cookies from your seb server to your browser, but that doesn't sound like something easy to do as you will probably need to write an extension to the browser

Comment: You don't want to send cookies around.